# Number of free indices on a tensor, how's it called?

Tags: terminology, tensor-calculus, definition, notation

Suppose we're working with a spin-$s$ field, represented by a totally symmetric tensor of order s (or *rank*, as we confusingly call it in physics), i.e.

$$\varphi_{\mu_1 \cdots \mu_s}$$

Assume that, other than $\varphi$, the theory contains numerical constants, the derivative vector $\partial_\mu$ and the flat metric tensor $\eta_{\mu \nu}$. Furthermore, the theory is linear is $\varphi$ and we can contract indices as we usually do.

Is there a name for the **number of free indices on $\varphi$** in a term?

For example, for $\partial_\mu \partial_\nu \varphi^\nu{}_{\sigma\lambda}$ that number would be **two** and for $\eta_{\mu\nu} \varphi^\lambda {}_\lambda$ the number would be **zero**.

Alternatively, how would you define that number mathematically without complicating things too much?

Comment: Rank.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I'm afraid that's correct, but it's extremely confusing to use that mathematical concept in the context of physics.

Comment: Why do you think it is confusing? I'm a physicists. I do physics. I use that word all the time.

Comment: I'm a physicist too, just for the record. It's confusing because *order* and *rank* of a tensor are two completely different things in mathematics, and physicists often refer to *rank* when they actually mean *order*.

Comment: By the  **number of free indices on**  $\:\varphi\:$ do you mean the number of independent components of a totally symmetric tensor with    $\:s\:$ indices taking values  in the range $\:1,2,3,\cdots ,d\:$ (here $d=4$) or something else?

Comment: I just mean the number of non-contracted indices (on the field tensor) in a term.

Answer (score 1):

> Let $V$ ve a finite-dimensional real vector space. If $k$ is a positive integer, a ***covariant k-tensor on*** $V$ is an element of the $k$-fold tensor product $V^* \otimes \cdots \otimes V^*$ (...). The number $k$ is called the ***rank*** of [the tensor].

From Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, with slight editing by me. A similar definition applies to contravariant tensors. If a tensor is mixed, technically the rank is not defined; instead we usually speak of a tensor of ***type*** $(k, l)$, though I guess you could call $k+l$ the rank if you really want.

Comment: Alright then, rank it is. I just hope it doesn't confuse people who confuse it with order.

Comment: @Ivan I have never heard of this being called "order". Rank is common both in math and physics books.

Comment: The confusion is explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_(intrinsic_definition)#Tensor_rank

Comment: Oh, now I understand the possible confusion. OP has a point. An $n\times n$ matrix is, according to OP, an order $2$ tensor, while its rank can be anything from $0$ to $n$ (its rank being defined as the dimension of the vector space spanned by its columns). I guess the terminology *could* be ambiguous. In this case, it's best that you define what you mean by "rank".